# What is the literal constructor for symbols?

Tags: ruby

I am learning about named constructors in Rails, and for the exercise we have to try to find the class hierarchy for a symbol. First, I have to create a symbol using a named constructor. I have tried both

```
    s = Symbol.new(:newsymbol)
```

and

```
    s = Symbol.new(:"newsymbol")
```

but both are telling me that "new" is an undefined method for the Symbol class. Is there something with the symbol class that doesn't allow the "new" method to be applied to it, or am I using an incorrect literal constructor for symbol?

Comment: "literal constructor" is an oxymoron. It's either a constructor call or a literal.

Comment: Also, there is no such thing as "named constructor" in ruby.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What is a "named constructor"? What is a "literal constructor"? What do symbols have to do with Rails? What do you mean by "applying a method to a class"?

Answer (score 2):

The Symbol class in Ruby doesn't have the Symbol#new method.  This has to do with symbols being unique.  To use the literal you would just use the leading semicolon.  Here are a few examples:

```
s = :s
s = :cat
s = :"A symbol with spaces in it"
```

Comment: It's just a [literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)), though, not a "literal constructor".

Comment: Hi, in my copy of the Well-Grounded Rubyist, the author actually says that symbols have a "literal constructor."  Not saying you're wrong though

Answer (score 0):

In you examples

```
s = Symbol.new(:new_symbol)
```

which won't run is equivalent to the following which does run

```
s = :new_symbol   # :new_symbol is already a symbol!
```

Now there IS a method that turns a string into a symbol:

```
s = "new_symbol".to_sym
```

which sets `s` with the value `:new_symbol`. Perhaps that was what you had in mind?

Comment: Technically speaking, `Symbol.new(:new_symbol)` is not equivalent to anything, because it is meaningless in ruby.

Comment: I agree, not 'equivalent' so much as 'is replaced by'?